# Cross domain authentication with jwt and 2 servers as secret_key shareholders

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, cross-domain

I'd want to know whether this approach is safe:

I have server A and B

User is logging in via server A, which uses User's credentials and generates valid JWT token with secret_key and then redirects user to server B with jwt in url? or via post?

And then server B validates that token due to fact, that it's using the same secret_key

Both servers are "mine" and HTTPS is being used.

Is that safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you propose is, in general, safe. Some things to consider:

- You could use public/private key pair so that server B cannot create tokens, only validate them.
- When redirecting, prefer POST method so that your users don't accidentally copy-paste a URL somewhere with a valid token in it.